# how to loop through arrays and print each index side by side in python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Simply put, I want to print three arrays with strings in between each. For example,

```
print(item + string + description + string + price).
```

I have the 3 arrays but this code only prints the first six lines.

```
res = "\n".join("{} {} {} {} {} {} {}".format(html, x, html, z, html, w, html) for x, y, z, v, w in zip(itemList, html, priceList, html, descripList)) 
print(res)
```

I'm surprised something simple like this is not already answered on Stack Overflow, everything I find is not practical but rather theoretical.

Here is my full code:

```
itemList=[]
for tag in soup.find_all('a', class_=['menuItem-name']):
    if tag not in itemList:
        itemList.append(tag.text)

descripList=[]
for t in soup.find_all('span', class_=['u-text-secondary']):
    if t not in descripList:
        descripList.append(t.text)

priceList=[]
for g in soup.find_all('p', class_=['menuItem-displayPrice']):
    if g not in priceList:
        priceList.append(g.text)

html="<html>"
res = "\n".join("{} {} {} {} {} {} {}".format(html, x, html, z, html, w, html) for x, y, z, v, w in zip(itemList, html, priceList, html, descripList))
print(res)
```

Comment: `string.join([item, description, price])` would get you the output of that example, but unclear what you mean by "six lines"

Comment: I have about 2k lines of each array and only get the first six, thank you for such a fast reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

putting "<html>" into zip will iterate through all 6 chars in that string and then finish. Try:

```
res = "\n".join("{} {} {} {} {} {} {}".format(html, x, html, z, html, w, html) for x, z, w in zip(itemList, priceList, descripList))
```

Answer (score 1):

`zip` is truncating its work at the shortest iterable passed to it; one of its arguments only has a length of 6

```py
>> [x for x in zip(range(3), range(4), range(5))]
[(0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2)]
```